# Finding and replacing all strings with variables (ruby)

Tags: regex

I noticed that VS Code has the ability to search using regex; however, I'm wondering if there's an easier way to replace all of the symbol assignments in my code with strings. For example:

- `:variable` would convert to `'variable'`
- `variable:` would convert to `'variable' =>`

Alternatively, I've tried to put together a bash script that would do this, but it seems that my matches are going beyond where it should stop. For example:

```
grep -RE "\[\:.*?\]" .
```

seems to be a good match, but if the line has more than one ], then it goes to the end. For example, this entire area gets matched:

```
[:test_recipient] : opts[:recipient:]
```

as opposed to

```
[:test_recipient]
```

and

```
[:recipient]
```

individually. How can I only grab up to the end of the first closing bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to exclude matching the square brackets

For example

```
echo "[:test_recipient] : opts[:recipient:]" | grep -Eo "\[:[^][]*]"
```

Output

```
[:test_recipient]
[:recipient:]
```